# Disable Section Header View on RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing NavigationDrawer with a custom RecyclerView.Adapter() and i have 2 views , one as a header view and another for list items.i want header view not being clickable , so i know that in BaseAdapter we can achieve this behavior by **areAllItemsEnabled()** and **isEnabled(int position)** but i wanted to know that is there an equivalent way in RecyclerView.Adapter()?